# Pyspark adding additional double quotes in array at saving time

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a small cluster setup of Spark 3.x. I have read some data and after transformations, I have to save it as JSON. But the problem I am facing is that, in array type of columns, Spark is adding extra double quotes when written as json  file.
Sample data-frame data
[image]

I am saving this data frame as JSON with following command

```
df.write.json("Documents/abc")
```

The saved output is as follows
[image]

Finally, the schema info is as follows
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of the string array contain double quotes within the data, e.g. the first element is `"Saddar Cantt, Lahore Punjab Pakistan"` instead of `Saddar Cantt, Lahore Punjab Pakistan`. You can remove the extra double quotes from the strings before writing the json with [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html#replace):

```python
df.withColumn("ADDRESS", F.expr("""transform(ADDRESS, a -> replace(a, '"'))""")) \
    .write.json("Documents/abc")
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I have to remove newline character instead of double quote.

Comment: @HafizMuhammadShafiq can you try `transform(ADDRESS, a -> replace(a, '\n'))`?

Answer (score 0):

If we enforce schema before writing the dataframe as json, I believe we can work around such issues without having to replace/change any characters.

Without schema ->

```
df.show()

id | address
1  | ['Saddar Cantt, Lahore Punjab Pakistan', 'Shahpur']


df.write.json("path")
```

**{"id":"1","address":["'Saddar Cantt, Lahore Punjab Pakistan'","'Shahpur'"]}**

With Schema ->

```
df = df.withColumn('address', F.col('address').cast(StringType()))
df = df.withColumn('address', F.from_json(F.col('address'), ArrayType(StringType())))
df.write.json("path")
```

**{"id":"1","address":["Saddar Cantt, Lahore Punjab Pakistan","Shahpur"]}**

from_json only takes string as input. Hence we need to first cast array to string.